# How to write a function that takes an Array of Ints and returns true (Bool) if all the numbers are odd

Tags: ios, swift

I want write swift and want result like this

```
func isOdd(getArray: [Int]) -> Bool{
    for i in getArray{
        if getArray[i] % 2 == 0{
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
}

let test1 = [2,4,6,8]
isOdd(test1)
```

Expected Result:

[image: result]

Comment: click image(result) to see result

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried?

Comment: func isOdd(getArray: [Int]) -> Bool{
 for i in getArray{
  if getArray[i] % 2 == 0{
   return true
  }else{
   return false
  }
 }
}

let test1 = [2,4,6,8]
isOdd(test1)

Comment: Your function only tests the 1st number.

Answer (score 7):

You need to check if your integer divided by 2 remainder is not equal to zero using the modulo operator `%`:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var isOdd: Bool { !isMultiple(of: 2) }
    var isEven: Bool { isMultiple(of: 2) }
}
```

---

```
(-4).isOdd // false
(-3).isOdd // true
(-2).isOdd // false
(-1).isOdd // true
0.isOdd    // false
1.isOdd    // true
2.isOdd    // false
3.isOdd    // true
4.isOdd    // false

(-4).isEven // true
(-3).isEven // false
(-2).isEven // true
(-1).isEven // false
0.isEven    // true
1.isEven    // false
2.isEven    // true
3.isEven    // false
4.isEven    // true
```

---

Then you have to check if all elements in your collection satisfy a predicate, in this case isOdd. You can accomplish that by extending Sequence constraining its elements to `BinaryInteger` and create a property that checks if the sequence allSatisfy the appropriate KeyPath (isOdd or isEven):

```
extension Sequence where Element: BinaryInteger {
    var allOdd: Bool { allSatisfy(\.isOdd) }
    var allEven: Bool { allSatisfy(\.isEven) }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let numbers = [2,4,6,8]

if numbers.allOdd {
    print(true)
} else {
    print(false)     // false
}    

if numbers.allEven {
    print(true)     // true
} else {
    print(false)    
}
```

Comment: Do you have easier than this way? thank you

Comment: I have added another usage sample

Comment: @HiResBank note that contains will stop at the first occurrence and if you have a huge array you don't have to go through all its elements.

Comment: @dfri thanks for the edit

Comment: @LeoDabus np; nice and clean answer btw (Y)!

Answer (score 3):

Your original code is close, but you don't want to return `true` until you have examined the entire array:

```
func isOdd(getArray: [Int]) -> Bool{
    for i in getArray{
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The advantage of a simple `for in` loop over `map` or `reduce` is that you can return as soon as you find the first even number rather than iterating over the entire array.

Comment: thank for answer // result away return true

Comment: It work!! thank @Paulw11

Comment: how to check empty array [] return true

Comment: This code will return `true` for an empty array since the loop won't execute.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: empty collection literal requires an explicit type

Comment: If you have something like `let x = []` you will get an error since Swift can't infer the type of `x`.  You need something like `let x:[Int] = []` to set the type explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

very short:

```
func isOdd(_ array: [Int]) -> Bool {
    return  !array.contains {($0 % 2) == 0 }
}
```